# Bind <select> to viewmodel in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-templates, model-binding

I have the following view model

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    public int SelectedCategoryId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CategoryDto> AvailableCategories { get; set; }
}
```

in my view I am using jquery template to bind my data to a `select` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  var categories = @Model.AvailableCategories.ToJson();
  var categoryMarkup = '<option value="${Id}"${Selected}>${Name}</option>';
  $.template("categoryTemplate", categoryMarkup);
  $.tmpl("categoryTemplate", categories).appendTo($('#categories'));
});
</script>

<select id="categories"></select>
```

What would I need to do to make sure my `SelectedCategoryId` viewmodel property gets populated on the POST? I'd prefer not to use the `Html.DropDownList` if I can get away with it

Answer (score 0):

Simply add it in your form using the html helpers. Ex.

```
Html.HiddenFor(o=>o.SelectCategoryId)
```

If your combo box is changing this then simply set an onchange event

```
("#selectId").change(function(){
//something like this - untested
$("#SelectCategoryId").val(this.value);
 });
```

Unless you are using an explicit jQuery .ajax() call in that case you will need to add this value to the data. Which are you using when you post? I don't see your form above anywhere